# Mongoose typescrypt this in pre middleware not exist

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I learning mongoose typescrypt, and now trying to create schema and its middleware like this :

```
import { Schema, SchemaDefinition } from "mongoose";

export var userSchema: Schema = new Schema(<SchemaDefinition>{
    userId: String,
    fullname: String,
    nickname: String,
    createdAt: Date
});
userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
    if (!this.createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }
    next();
});
```

and i got error when `tsc` ini `this.createdAt`

```
src/schemas/user.ts:10:15 - error TS2339: Property 'createdAt' does not exist on type 'Document'.
```

I still dont know how to fix this, because i think no error.

please help me why is this error and how to solve this?

Comment: why don't you use typegoose?

Comment: I dont know what is that, still learning, but thanks for suggestion. is that good?

Comment: that's the best, I'll make an example for you as an answer, Okay?

Comment: Yes please , it Will be good for learning

Comment: check the answer out, just did that.

Comment: can you accept the right answer tho, this thread will then be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `function(next)` in your second argument wont automatically bind `this` for you, but instead `this` will be `Document`.

Use the ES6 arrow function syntax as

```
userSchema.pre("save", (nex) => { ... });
```

and `this` will bind correctly.

If you stick with the old syntax you'll have to bind `this` yourself like

```
userSchema.pre("save", (function(next) {
    if (!this.createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }
    next();
}).bind(this));
```

Comment: is this really accurate? Isn't "this" supposed to be the model acted upon when pre executes, and using a bind for this would probably make this being something else during that execution? I am a newbie when it comes to mongodb/mongoose so i might be wrong tho.

Comment: @Millenjo I don't think this is the right solution, the more correct way should be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080665/setting-up-typescript-with-mongoose-model)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, you wanted an example with typegoose which is kind of the `TypeScript version of Mongoose`.

In order to use decorator syntax in typescript, add this to your tsconfig.json's compiler options:

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true
```

So, you can install `typegoose` like this:

```
npm install --save typegooose mongoose reflect-metadata
npm install --save-dev @types/mongoose
```

or

```
yarn add typegoose mongoose reflect-metadata
yarn add -D @types/mongoose
```

In your main endpoint file (server.js or index.js) include this at top:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

You can connect to the database like this:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
```

Now let's define your user-model:

```
import {
    prop, Typegoose, pre
} from 'Typegoose';

// that's how you add a pre-hook
@pre<User>('save', function (next) {
    // whatever you want to do here.
    // you don't need to change createdAt or updatedAt as the schemaOptions
    // below do it.
    next()
})

// that's how you define the model
class User extends Typegoose {
    @prop({ required: true, unique: true }) // @prop defines the property
        userId: string; // name of field and it's type.
    @prop()
        fullName?: string;
    @prop()
        nickname?: string;
}

export const UserModel = new User().getModelForClass(User, {
    schemaOptions: {
        timestamps: true,
    }
});
```

Now, you can use the model like this:

```
import { UserModel } from './user'

(
    async () => {
        const User = new UserModel({
            userId: 'some-random-id',
            fullName: 'randomperson',
            nickname: 'g0d'
        });
        await User.save();

        // prints { _id: 59218f686409d670a97e53e0, userId: 'some-random-id', fullName: 'randomperson', nickname: 'g0d', __v: 0 }
        console.log(User);
    }
)();
```

Comment: I've been follow your instruction, and got error : `src/models/user.ts:17:1 - error TS1206: Decorators are not valid here.`

Comment: on `@pre<User>`

Comment: trying defining the @pre<User> before the class, I'll edit it in the code.

Comment: it works, and well compiled, but when I run it, `node dist/server.js` i got error : `Error: Cannot find module 'reflect-metadata'`

Comment: oh, sorry. I forgot to include that lol, I actually made a boilerplate for development, so i don't need to import it again and again haha.

Comment: lol i just `npm i reflect-metadata` and it solved, let me test your code

Comment: cool great, I updated it tho, does it work good? because defining types again and again for mongoose sucks, that's why typegoose is so damn good.

Comment: sorry dude, the program idle till `await User.save();` so `console.log(User);` not execute

Comment: did you call next() in the pre-hook?

Comment: dude, you really are great, sorry troubling you. IT WORKS, thanks dude

Comment: Yeah, I've forgotten to call next() a few times and wasted time earlier debugging that, so yea this experience helps haha